# Warum ist der Ausdruck nicht „Sehr geehrte Frauen und Herren“?

Tags: phrase, politeness

Wenn man eine Person höflich ansprechen will, sagt man entweder *Frau Blabla* oder *Herr Blabla*. Die Pluralform von *Frau* ist *Frauen*, und die von *Herr* ist *Herren*.

Wieso denn lautet die höfliche Ansprache „Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren“ und nicht „Sehr geehrte Frauen und Herren“? Hat *Frau* zwei Pluralformen, von denen nur *Damen* in diesem Kontext zulässig ist? (im Gegensatz zur Pluralform *Frauen*)

Comment: *Frau* und *Herr* sind die höflichen Anreden für eine Frau oder einen Mann. Das "Gegenwort" für Mann ist *Frau*, jedoch für *Herr* ist es nunmal *Dame* und nicht *Frau*. Warum das so ist...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Also wieso ist die höfliche Anrede für eine Frau nicht "Dame", wenn die höfliche Anrede für einen Mann ist nicht "Mann"?

Comment: @William Häh? Frau ist eine weibliche Person, Mann eine männliche Person. Die höflichen Formen sind Dame und Herr. Punkt. Bei "Frauen und Herren" vermischst du zwei Formen.

Comment: Auf Englisch heißt Frau *woman*. Man sagt aber *Ladys and Gentlemen* und dennoch spricht man eine Frau mit *Miss* oder *Misses* an... Du sagst da ja auch nicht *Dear women and men* or address a woman as *Good morning, women Miller!*. Es gibt Wörter für die Anrede (*Dame*, *Herr*) und Wörter, die die "Art der Person" bestimmen (*Frau*, *Mann*).

Comment: See also http://gfds.de/anrede-herr-und-frau-statt-herr-und-dame/

Comment: There is already an English version of this question [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3725/1696).

Comment: @guidot No it's not the same question

Answer (score 6):

Früher gab es diese beiden Paare:

- > Das Weib - der Mann

  Das davon abgeleitete Gegensatzpaar *weiblich - männlich* ist noch heute in Verwendung.
- > Die Frau - der Herr

  Dieses Paar findet man in Anreden (»Sehr geehrte *Frau* Maier«, »sehr geehrter *Herr* Müller«)

Erst später wurde aus dem Französischen das Wort »Dame« importiert, das als edler und gehobener als das Wort »Frau« empfunden und verwendet wurde. Einen edleren Ersatz für den Herren gibt es aber nicht. Will man nun eine gemischtgeschlechtliche Gruppe erwachsener Menschen möglichst höflich anreden, so greift man zu den jeweils hochwertigsten Begriffen. Daraus ergibt sich dieses Paar:

- > die Dame - der Herr

  Das findet man nicht nur in der nachgefragten Plural-Anrede (»Meine sehr verehrten Damen und Herren«), sondern auch, wenn höflich über Einzelpersonen gesprochen wird (»Der *Herr* an Tisch fünf möchte zahlen«, »Die *Dame* mit dem grünen Mantel hat das Zimmer 42 reserviert«)

Gleichzeitig wurde das Weib abgewertet, so dass der Mann heute als Partnerin meist nicht mehr ein Weib, sondern eine Frau hat:

- > die Frau - der Mann

  »Markus und Nadine sind seit 3 Wochen verheiratet, sie sind jetzt Mann und Frau.« Dieses Gegensatzpaar wird standardmäßig auch verwendet, um Unterschiede zwischen den Geschlechtern zu thematisieren (»Männer sind vom Mars, Frauen von der Venus« - Niemand würde hier die Männer durch Herren ersetzen, oder Frauen durch Damen oder Weiber)

Die Pluralanrede »meine Damen und Herren« ist vergleichbar mit dem englischen »Ladies and Gentlemen«, verwendet also die ehrvollsten Begriffe, die angebracht sind.

Bei Einzel-Anreden werden auch im Englischen andere Begriffe verwendet (»Mr. Johnson«, »Mrs. Smith«). Im Deutschen bleib hier weiterhin das oben genannte Paar Frau-Herr in Verwendung.

Answer (score 3):

Ich zitiere von einer [Webseite](https://www.rechtsanwalt.com/urteil/sehr-geehrte-frauen-und-herren).

> Ob die Anrede weiblicher Personen als 'Dame' diskriminierend und damit
>   verfassungswidrig ist, beschäftigt immer wieder die Gerichte. Sowohl
>   das OVG Lüneburg als auch das Bundesverfassungsgericht verneinten
>   diese Frage.
>
> Das Bundesverfassungsgericht betrieb in seiner Urteilsbegründung sogar
>   Sprachforschung: Die Bezeichnung 'Dame' ist seit 1622 im deutschen
>   Sprachgebrauch bekannt. Ab Mitte des 17. Jahrhunderts sank 'Dame' in
>   der Volkssprache auf die Bedeutung 'Hofmätresse' und 'Dirne' ab. Erst
>   seit dem 18. Jahrhunderts hat sich 'Dame' in der bürgerlichen
>   Gesellschaft als 'Ehrentitel' eingebürgert. 'Frau' als Anrede habe
>   sich jedoch, so die Damen bzw. Frauen und Herren Richter
>   übereinstimmend, nicht durchgesetzt.
>
> Also bleibt es wie gehabt bei der Anrede 'Sehr geehrte Damen und
>   Herren'.

Ich weiß nicht ob es Deine Frage beantwortet, aber zumindest zeigt es, dass dieses Thema schon seit langem diskutiert wird.

Answer (score 2):

Du hast recht, die alltägliche Anrede ist *Herr Mayr* und *Frau Mayr.* Doch das klingt viel einfacher als es ist.

In keinem Kontext außerhalb der Anrede sind *Herr* und *Frau* gleichgestellt. Üblicherweise ist das Antonym von *Frau* nicht *Herr* sondern *Mann.* Dabei bezeichnet *Mann* ein Exemplar der Spezies *Homo sapiens,* dessen Karyogramm als 46 XY angenommen werden kann, und *Frau* ein Exemplar derselben Spezies, dessen Karyogramm als 46 XX angenommen werden kann (so die möglichst biologische und möglichst diskriminationsfreie Definition). Das lässt sich an den folgenden Gegensatzpaaren sehen:

- > Gott schuf den Menschen nach seinem Bild, er schuf **Mann und Frau.** (1. Mose 1:27; Gute-Nachricht-Übersetzung)
- > Erzieher wird oft als **Frauen**beruf, Kfz-Mechaniker als **Männer**beruf wahrgenommen.
- > Die **Männer**umkleide ist den Gang runter und dann rechts, die **Frauen**umkleide den Gang runter und dann links.

*Mann* oder *Männer* hier durch *Herr* oder *Herren* zu ersetzen würde seltsam wirken.

---

Das übliche Antonym zu *Herr* ist wie oben angedeutet auch nicht *Frau* sondern *Dame.* Diese beiden Wörter waren Ehrenbezeichnungen, die unter den »klassischen« Adelstiteln wie *Fürst* oder *Graf* standen. Aus einer selbsterniedrigenden Position heraus – in alten Zeiten als Diener, heutzutage als Kellner oder Servicemitarbeiter – würde man ausschließlich *Herr* oder *Dame* benutzen. Wenn man dieses Gegensatzpaar in der oben erwähnten Bedeutung *Mann/Frau* benützt, wirkt es gehoben oder besonders höflich.

- > Was darf ich dem Herrn zu trinken bringen? Und der Dame?
- > Jawohl, mein Herr/meine Dame!
- > Die Herrenrunde findet im grünen Salon statt, die Damen treffen sich im blauen Salon.

Auch hier gilt: *Dame* durch *Frau* zu ersetzen wäre mindestens seltsam – wahrscheinlich würde es aber als Diskriminierung angesehen (denn man würde für den Herrn einen Ehrentitel verwenden, für die Dame ein Allerweltswort).

Da Anreden in aller Regel besonders höflich sein sollen, ist es keine Frage, dass sie *Damen* und *Herren* verwenden, anstatt *Frauen* und *Männer*.

---

**Hinweis:** Alle Beispiele in dieser Antwort dienen nur dazu, *ein Gegensatzpaar* zu verdeutlichen. Sprich, wenn im einen Satz *X* gesagt wird, müsste im nächsten *Y* statt *B* folgen. Außer dem wörtlichen Genesiszitat kann in fast allen Fällen *Mann* durch *Herr* und *Frau* durch *Dame* (und umgekehrt) ersetzt werden, solange dies parallel geschieht.

Comment: Was unterscheidet dann die Umkleide vom Rad? Und seit wann gilt ausgerechnet die Bibel als diskriminationsfrei?

Comment: "Die Herrenumkleide ist vorne rechts" ist doch ein üblicher Satz? Genauso wie die Damentoilette, die Damenumkleide etc. Generell stimme ich dir zu und finde die Antwort sehr gelungen, aber das Beispiel ist vielleicht etwas unglücklich?

Comment: @AndreasHeese Ich habe mit den Beispielen eigentlich ausdrücken wollen, dass wenn ich für das eine *Herren-* nehme, ich für das andere *Damen-* nehmen muss/sollte und nicht *Frauen-*.

Comment: @userunknown Was denn für ein Rad?

Comment: Damenrad und Herrenrad.

Comment: @userunknown Ah, *das* Radl. Prinzipiell nichts, nur dass man häufiger von *Herren-* und *Damenradln* spricht als von *Männer-* und *Frauenradln*. Wie im Edit hinzugefügt geht es mir primär darum, dass man nicht *Männerumkleide* gefolgt von *Damenumkleide* benutzen sollte.

Comment: Ja, wieso sollte man das nicht? Erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Weil *Mann* und *Dame* nicht dem gleichen Bedeutungsregister angehören.

Comment: In anderen Übersetzungen vom 1. Mose 1,27 liest man: »Da schuf Gott den Menschen in seinem Bild, im Bild Gottes schuf er ihn; **Mann und *Weib*** schuf er sie.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Deswegen habe ich explizit die Übersetzung mit angegeben. Die Gute-Nachricht-Übersetzung wurde erst in den Achtzigerjahren fertiggestellt.

Comment: @Jan: Du hast dieses Zitat aber als Beleg für das Paar »Mann-Frau« verwendet. Tatsächlich belegt es aber gar nichts, weil es Varianten desselben Zitats gibt, die dem Mann keine Frau, sondern ein Weib zuordnen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Eine deutlich archaischere Übersetzung (auch wenn die Sprache der heutigen leicht angepasst ist) widerlegt aber schwerlich den heutigen Gebrauch.

Comment: Wenn ich den heutigen Gebrauch eines Wortes belegen wollte, würde ich einen ganz großen Bogen um jede Bibelübersetzung machen.

Comment: Gebenedeit bist,Du, @HubertSchölnast ! :)

Comment: Dass Mann und Dame nicht dem gleichen Bedeutungsregister angehören ist ja der Ausgangspunkt der Frage - Du argumentierst zirkulär.

Comment: @userunknown Die Frage stellt nur fest, dass es *Damen und Herren* heißt, und vermutet deswegen, dass *Frau* zwei Pluralformen habe (was falsch ist).